# What is the simplest way to route web traffic via separate (dedicated) interface?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, configuration, linux-networking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iptables - Target to route packet to specific interface?](https://serverfault.com/questions/345111/iptables-target-to-route-packet-to-specific-interface)

Ubuntu 12.04. So on the client's machines I've got two NICs `eth1` and `wlan0`. I'd like all the web browsing traffic to go through `wlan0` and the rest via `eth1`. What is **the simplest** way to achieve that? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you'll have to use a policy based routing - mark outgoing packets to the port 80, then use separate routing table for them. take a look [here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7134) and just google for *[linux policy routing](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=linux%20policy%20routing)*.

Comment: I was actually hoping for `iptables` guru to give me the exact commands rather than abstract. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Then maybe your question should reflect what answer you are hoping for? i.e. maybe you should include "Could someone provide the exact iptables commands to achieve this?"

Comment: @tkane - i've done it few times but do not have example at hand. you'll -j MARK packets on prerouting [eg just for outgoing traffic on port 80], then you'll use "ip rule add fwmark markNumber table someRoutingTableNumber" to direct traffic to separate routing table. you'll need to create that table and add default route to it.